# SQL equivalents queries

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I don't know anyone who can tell me if those queries equivalents?

```
SELECT 
TOP 1 (XP.COL1 * XP.COL2) 
FROM XP 
INNER JOIN XZ 
ON XZ = XP 
WHERE XZ = 'ZORD'
ORDER BY XP DESC
```

And

```
SELECT 
MAX(XP.COL1 * XP.COL2)
FROM 
XP,
XZ
WHERE
XZ = XP 
AND XZ = 'ZORD'
```

Comment: `ORDER BY XP DESC` -- Isn't XP a table ? Assuming you meant to order by `(XP.COL1 * XP.COL2)`, then yes - they will yield the same result. Query 1- you perform the multiplication and order them in descending manner, meaning the max value comes to the top, and you select only that value. The more easier second query directly gives you the max value

Comment: Yes, I've just seen my mistake about the ORDER BY.

Thank you Gary

Answer (score 2):

First, you should *always* use proper `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

However, that is irrelevant to your question.

Your queries are not identical.  In particular, `MAX()` ignores `NULL` values whereas `ORDER BY . . . DESC` will place them first.

If the expression `XP.COL1 * XP.COL2` is never `NULL`, then the two are equivalent.  However, they are not in general the same.

Comment: Totally forgot about the null treatment! Also, what's wrong in avoiding join keyword for inner joins ? Does it have to do with execution time ?

Comment: @Gary . . . Explicit `JOIN` syntax was introduced over 20 years ago.  It is more powerful.  And pretty much everyone familiar with the topic agrees that it is more readable and less prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
    SELECT (XP.COL1*XP.COL2) as res
    FROM XP INNER JOIN XZ ON XP.col=xz.col
    Where XZ.cols='zord'
    Order by XP.col DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;







    SELECT max(res) 
    FROM (SELECT (XP.COL1*XP.COL2) as res
    FROM XP INNER JOIN XZ ON XP.col=xz.col
    Where XZ.col='zord') ;
```